# How can i store the results returned by a method into an array for further use? (Java)

Tags: arrays, methods

I am trying to store the results returned from a method into an array, however I don´t know which would be the best way to do it.

public class Wealth {

METHOD
double taxes() {
         return (0.08*riquezaEnCarros) + (0.15*riquezaEnCasas);

ARRAY?

double []  = taxes();

NEW EDIT

```
double riquezaTotalHijo() {
    return riquezaEnEfectivo + riquezaEnCarros + riquezaEnCasas - 
    impuestosHijo() + riquezaTotalPadre();
}

public ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(riquezaTotalHijo());

}
```

Comment: You need to create the array first.

Comment: Ok. I create the array first, then the method and after that, what should I do?

Comment: I didn't mean you need to create the array before the function but rather before you can store anything in it. Create the array, call the function, store the result in the previously created array.

Comment: But how do i store the results in the array?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using array then we can assume that you want to call method multiple times
Let if you want to call it 5 times

```
List<double> list = new ArrayList<double>();
for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
{
//Add values to array list
list.add(taxes());
}
//ArrayList list have values now
//Now you can loop on array list to use values 
for (double val : list) {
System.out.println(val); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am beginner, so if I don't know the size of the array, how do I use "Arraylist"?

Comment: Thank you. If I want to add more than five elements to the array, I just have to modify the for loop or is there another way to do it?

Comment: You must have to decide how many times you want to call that method, it can be any variable value which you can change on runtime

Comment: I assumed it 5 to show you that multiple values can be added, you can call method even without for loop, ArrayList will have as many elements as many times you will call taxes() inside list.add()

Comment: Thank you again. See the new edit i add in the post. I am using Eclipse and when i try to store the method riquezaTotalHijo() in the array as you said, I get this error "Duplicate method riquezaTotalHijo() in type Hijo"

Comment: It's not a problem related to ArrayList, it's simply that you have one more method of same name 'riquezaTotalHijo'